# TraslatePress widget on Mobile

Tags: wordpress, widget, translate, off-canvas-menu, language-switching

The Language switcher widget doesn't display properly on mobile and iPad view, in the off-canvas menu.I upload an image to understand what is the issue.(https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkuIb.jpg)

I don't understand what I have to do, I try to change the setting of the widget, but it doesn't change anything. I also try with other widget, but they are shown properly, so I think it is a problem of the language switcher. I use both language switcher Block and the shortcode.